# "unexpected end of input" in `dhall repl`

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, dhall

I can evaluate dhall expressions with `dhall --file ...`, and I can evaluate `1 + 1` in the repl, but typing a `let` expression into `dhall repl` fails with "unexpected end of input."

```
➜  cat test.dhall
let x = 1

let y = 2

in  x + y
➜  ~ dhall --file test.dhall
3
➜  ~ dhall repl
Welcome to the Dhall v1.41.0 REPL! Type :help for more information.
⊢ let x = 1

Error: Invalid input

(input):2:1:
  |
2 | <empty line>
  | ^
unexpected end of input
expecting "→", ->, :, keyword, or whitespace

⊢ 1 + 1

2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let x = 1` by itself is not a valid expression. The structure of a `let ... in ...` expression is such that it can start with one or more `let` clauses, but must end with the `in` clause.

If you *just* want to set a value in the REPL, you need to use the special `:let` command (which is specific to the REPL and not part of the language).

```
⊢ :let x = 1

x : Natural

⊢ x + 1

2
```

Comment:  thank you! I see now that there _is_ an `in` at the end of this block of code, but I didn't read the document entirely before I wanted to try expressions from it: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/dhall/

Comment: It's slightly different than in Haskell, where you would write something like `let x = 1; y = 2; in x + y` instead of `let x = 1; let y = 2; in x + y`.